# Get JSON data 404 (Not Found)

Tags: json, jquery-mobile

OK this is strange. I am getting the following error when i try to test my code. For some reason, my URL address is showing as twice.

```
GET http://howtodeployit.com/howtodeployit.com/api/get_recent_posts/ 404 (Not Found)
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blogposts', function() {     
    //$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();    
        $.ajax({
            url: "http:/howtodeployit.com/api/get_recent_posts/",
            dataType: "json",
            jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); },

            complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); },
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            // successful request; do something with the data
              $('#postlist').empty();
              var html = '';
                for (i=0; i<data.posts.length; i++) {
                html += '<li>' + data.posts.title + '</li>';
               }
               $("#postlist").append(html).listview("refresh");
             },

            error: function (request,error) {
                alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: url: "http:/howtodeployit.com/api/get_recent_posts/"

Try fixing http://

Comment: Are you using `json` or `jsonp`?  Why are you using a domain in the request at all?

Comment: I am working based off an example. That url gets me the JSON feeds. Is this correct? Must the url point to json file?

Comment: Place `.listview('refresh')` at the end of ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing second slash here: `"http:/howtodeployit.com/api/get_recent_posts/"`, you probably want `"http://howtodeployit.com/api/get_recent_posts/"`

Comment: I can't believe me, unbelievable

Comment: It's only natural to be unable to believe unbelievable ;)

Comment: Sorry based on the above code, why am I getting this "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Comment: This is different problem, probably your listview is not initialized?