# Uncaught ReferenceError: refresh is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I am trying to get my posts in content id = postlist styled and I have ready that i need to refresh the page (refresh). But for some reason I am getting 'refresh is not defined' error and my displayed posts are not styled.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blogposts', function() {     
    //$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();    
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=recentstories&callback=",
            dataType: "json",
            jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); },
            complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); },
            success:function(data){
                var result = '';
                $.each(data.posts.slice(0,4), function(i, val) {
                result = $('<li/>').append([$("<h3>", {html: val.title}),$("<p>", {html: val.excerpt})]).wrapInner('<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>').appendTo('#postlist');
                //return (i !== 4);
           });

           $(result).listview(refresh);
           },
```

Comment: where is no variable called `refresh`, what is it?

Comment: Can't see that the `refresh` in `$(result).listview(refresh);` is defined anywhere. If it is ment as a string-aprameter, try wrapping it in '' (`$(result).listview('refresh');`)

Comment: Do you mean `$(result).listview('refresh');`?

Comment: Is postlist a "UL" element? Then it should be

$("#postlst").listview("refresh")

Comment: As I mentioned in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503454/get-json-data-404-not-found#comment28933468_19503454) on one of your questions, place it at the end of `$.ajax()`. Also, if you're adding a fresh `ul` use `.listview()`, when appending items to an existing `ul` use `.listview('refresh')`.

Comment: Thanks Omar I just fixed it now, I added this $("#postlist").listview(); before the close of the success function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dynamically adding a new `data-role="listview"` to a page, use `$(".selector").listview()` to call widget enhancement.

When adding items to an existing `data-role="listview"`, use `$(".selector").listview("refresh")` to re-enhance the widget.

Answer (score 1):

[refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh) is a method name, so you need to pass it as a string leteral

```
$(result).listview('refresh');
```

or you need to declare a variable var refresh = 'refresh', then use the variable like `$(result).listview(refresh)`

Comment: Go for the first variant.

Comment: OK I missed the '', but now getting error 'Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'