# How to apply themes to html inside append() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to append some html tags from my javascript file. I found that themes(styles) are not applied in my newly added html elements inside append method. I'm using jquery mobile css and js for styles in my html file. Here is my js file;

```
var callback;

function call(uid,pw) { 
            callback=true;

        $.getJSON("json.jsp" + "?uid=" + uid + "&rdm=" + Math.random(), 
            function(data){ 
                var arr=data.menu.split(",");
                $("#cont").empty();
                $.each( arr, function( key, val ) {
                $( "#cont").append("<ul data-role='listview' data-divider-theme='b' data-inset='true'><li data-theme='c'><a href='#page1' data-transition='slide'>" + val + "</a></li></ul>");
                });
                callback=false;
                }      
        );
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: refresh is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513121/uncaught-referenceerror-refresh-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like

```
if ($('#cont').hasClass('ui-listview')) {
   $('#cont').listview('refresh');
} else {
   $('#cont').trigger('create');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var callback;

function call(uid,pw) { 
    callback=true;
    $.getJSON("json.jsp" + "?uid=" + uid + "&rdm=" + Math.random(), 
        function(data){ 
            var arr=data.menu.split(",");
            $("#cont").empty();
            $.each( arr, function( key, val ) {
                $( "#cont").append("<ul data-role='listview' data-divider-theme='b' data-inset='true'><li data-theme='c'><a href='#page1' data-transition='slide'>" + val + "</a></li></ul>");                    

            });
            $('#cont').trigger('create');
            $('[data-role="listview"]').listview('refresh');
            callback=false;
        }      
    );
}
```